# Kimurai in RoR - Get current_user in parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, kimurai

I am trying [kimurai framework](https://github.com/vifreefly/kimuraframework) for rails with devise

app/models/products_spider.rb

```rb
class ProductsSpider < Kimurai::Base
  @name = 'products_spider'
  @engine = :mechanize

  def self.process(url, user)
    @start_urls = [url]
    self.crawl!
  end

  def parse(response, url:, data: {})
    Rails.logger.info "*** Spider - Start parsing"
    Rails.logger.info "    url: #{url}"
    response.xpath("//div[@class='product floatleft span6 vertical-separator' or @class='product floatleft span6 ']").each do |product|
      item = {}
      item[:title] = product.css('h2.h-pr-title')&.text&.squish
      item[:descr] = product.css('p.product_s_desc')&.text&.squish
      item[:url] = URI.parse(url).merge(URI.parse(product.css('h2.h-pr-title a')[0]["href"])).to_s
      item[:img_url] = URI.parse(url).merge(URI.parse(product.css('img')[0]["src"])).to_s
      item[:price_cents] = product.css('span.PricesalesPrice')&.text.gsub(',', '.').to_f * 100
      item[:published] = true
      item[:categories] = response.xpath("//ul[@class='breadcrumb']/li[@class='active']/span").text.squish

      add_event(:custom, :rec_total)
      Product.where(item).first_or_create
      if Product.where(item).exists?
        add_event(:custom, :rec_exists)
      else
        Product.create!(item)
        add_event(:custom, :rec_new)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Inside parse I want to:

- get the current_user (devise session), or
- somehow I can pass the user info to parse, or
- I can use the `parse!` which can return the `items` array but in this case how can I know if the process completed ok or with errors? When using `crawl!` it returns the `response` which contains this info...

app/controllers/products_controller.rb

```rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def scrape
    url = 'https://manitaropolio.gr/proionta-manitaria/apoksiramena-manitaria'
    flash.now[:notice] = "Scrape Url: #{url}"
    response = ProductsSpider.process(url, current_user)
    if response[:status] == :completed && response[:error].nil?
      flash.now[:notice] = "Completed succesfully (added: #{response[:events][:custom][:rec_new]}, existed: #{response[:events][:custom][:rec_exists]}, total: #{response[:events][:custom][:rec_total]})"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = response[:error]
    end
  rescue StandardError => e
    flash.now[:alert] = "Error: #{e}"
  end
```

config/routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :products do
    match '/scrape', to: 'products#scrape', via: :post, on: :collection
  end

  root to: "public#home"
end
```

app/views/products/index.html.erb

```rb
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Products</h1>

<% if can? :scrape, Product %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <%= button_to 'Scrape', scrape_products_path %>
    </div>
    <% if @products.size > 0 %>
      <div class="col text-right">
        <%= "Count: #{@products.count}" %>
        <%= " (Total Count: #{Product.count})" if current_user.role?(:admin) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas on how can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Would you mind sharing code you tried? Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just did it... Thank you for pointing it out... :)

Comment: Where are you using `ProductsSpider`, in controller? can you please share that code as well?

Comment: In the `scrape` method... I add it in the main body above..

Comment: From where the scrape getting used?

Comment: it is an action of the ProductsController... user in UI press a button which executes the action...

Comment: The problem with this code is that your spider is doing way to much and will be insanely hard to test. It should just be responsible for crawling the page and returning an array of hashes. Create a separate service object or ActiveJob that actually takes the scraped data and creates model instances from it.

Comment: Yes you are correct
In this case I can use the `parse!` method and get the `items` array, but I do not know how can I get the completion status...
see my main message...